# How to append array data to spreadsheet rows using Google Script?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, append

I have created a script to retrieve data from REST API. I can view all the array data in logger. How do I add all those data into rows. This is my current function:

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("test")
  mainSheet.getRange('A1:A3').clear();

  var apiKey = 'test';

  var URL_STRING = "test";

  var url = URL_STRING + "?ApiKey=" + apiKey;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var arr = [];
  //Logger.log(data.output.o1);

  for (var i=0;i<data.output.o1.length;i++){
    x=(data.output.o1[i].company_name);
    arr.push(x);
    Logger.log(arr);
  } 
}
```

This is the sample output for arr:

[image]

This is my expected output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the values of `arr` from row 2 of the column "A" in the sheet "test".

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for (var i=0;i<data.output.o1.length;i++){
  x=(data.output.o1[i].company_name);
  arr.push(x);
  Logger.log(arr);
}
```

#### To:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.output.o1.length; i++) {
  x = (data.output.o1[i].company_name);
  arr.push([x]); // Modified
  Logger.log(arr);
}
mainSheet.getRange(2, 1, arr.length).setValues(arr); // Added
```

- If you want to append the values to the sheet, please modify `mainSheet.getRange(2, 1, arr.length).setValues(arr);` as follows.

  ```
    mainSheet.getRange(mainSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, arr.length).setValues(arr);
  ```

#### References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: i got an error saying Error 
Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 2.

Comment: Btw i tried this method. It can work.
  for (var i=0;i<data.output.o1.length;i++){
    x=(data.output.o1[i].company_name);
    Logger.log(x);
    mainSheet.appendRow([x]);

  }

Comment: How do i append this in specific row and column?

Comment: @Sriram Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In that case, can you provide the sample values of `arr` after your for loop? And also, can you add your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm your situation. I thought that the error message of `The data has 1 but the range has 2.` means that you might use the script `getRange(2, 1, arr.length, 2)` instead of `getRange(2, 1, arr.length)`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have added the sample output for arr

Comment: @Sriram Thank you for replying and adding more information. Unfortunately, I cannot find your current script for replicating your issue of `The data has 1 but the range has 2.`. Can you also add your current script for replicating your issue? By the way, I saw your added image, it seems that your output situation is different from your input values. For example, you want to remove the space between `Company` and `1`?

Comment: Sorry it is working. I forgot to add this arr.push([x]);